# Draw rounded rect border with no bottom border

Tags: ios, swift

I can draw a rounded corner at top left and right with that code

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
      let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
      let mask = CAShapeLayer()
      mask.path = path.cgPath
      layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

but what i want is a rounded rect at top left and top right with no bottom border, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why draw a bezierPath and apply mask when you can directly do this to your view?

```
yourView.layer.masksToBounds = true
yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 20 //your radius
yourView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
```

This will round the top-left and top-right corners of your view

Comment: Do consider accepting the answer if this helps (the tick at the side :-)) Happy coding!